# Updating Input text using jQuery on the fly

Tags: jquery

I am working on a form using jQuery. In the form i am trying to update a field as soon as user type inputs. Pretty much like, when user type some special characters it removes them and update the text at the same time. I am using jquery for the same. However my code is not working.

Here is what i did:

Form code:

```
<form name="user">
   <input name="appShortName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputappShortName" placeholder="Application Name">
</form>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(function(){
   $('#appShortName').keyup(function(){
      $('#appShortName').textreplace(/[^\w]/gi, '');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `#inputappShortName` instead of `#appShortName`

```
$('#inputappShortName').keyup(function(){
    var newValue = $(this).val().replace(/[^\w]/gi, '')
    $(this).val(newValue);
});
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/har1236/Q4WPP/)

Comment: where do i add this code ? it is not working when i added this under script under document.ready

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `val()` as a getter, and `val('value')` as a setter. Try this:

```
$('#appShortName').keyup(function(){
    var newValue = $(this).val().replace(/[^\w]/gi, '')
    $(this).val(newValue);
});
```

Also, the `id` of the attribute in your HTML and the jQuery selector do not match, is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,Shorter version

```
    $(function(){
       $('#inputappShortName').keyup(function(){
           this.value = this.value.textreplace(/[^\w]/gi, '');
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have try this code.

```
$('#inputappShortName').keyup(function(){
    var newValue = $(this).val().replace(/[^\w]/gi, '')
    $(this).text(newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to target the input field without the id you can use this:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="appShortName"]').keyup(function(){
        var newValue = $(this).val().replace(/[^\w]/gi, '')
        $(this).val(newValue);
    });
});
```

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x65St/